# wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected C++ - What could possibly be causing these error?

Tags: c++, string, loops, printing

I am getting an error saying wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected`

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    string A,B,C;
    cin>>A>>B;
    int i,len;
    len=A.length();
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(A[i]==B[i])
        C[i]='0';
        
      else
        C[i]='1';
    
    }
    cout<<C;

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the input to the program? When do you get the error?

Comment: Also `C[i]='0'` is undefined since you're accessing an element in an uninitialized string. You should use [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back). Same is the case with `B[i]`. What if length of `B` is less than that of `A`?

Comment: @Zoso  No the length of A and B will be same always , also I am getting the error as " wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected " which basically means my output is empty/blank

Comment: @Zoso Also check this code, https://github.com/fuwutu/CodeForces/blob/master/61A%20-%20Ultra-Fast%20Mathematician.cppthere is nothing different in the logic except the third string I've used..

Comment: And that's exactly why your code is incorrect. Your use of the third string is erroneous. Why do you think `C[i]` should give you a valid value?

Comment: @Zoso can you tell me the problem with it ? Like if you've checked the above code..also append() is working fine. I want to learn that why it won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it would be useful to know where the error occurred.  Running this code sample inside of an online c++ compiler gives me no error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are writing to uninitialized memory. When you create a `std::string` as such

```
std::string C
```

This string doesn't have any elements and it's backing character array is most probably empty. You can check that by doing `C.size()` and it shall return 0. So doing something like `C[0]` in such a state is undefined behaviour since you're writing to an *empty* string. You can easily check that by changing `C[i]` to `C.at(i)` (using the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function) and you should hit into an [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) error. As the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at#:%7E:text=No%20bounds%20checking%20is%20performed) states for `operator[]`,

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. ***No
> bounds checking is performed***.

and thus your current program *might appear* to work fine but isn't.

Changing that to [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)/`append` works because these functions take care of increasing the size of the backing character array of the string(if required) and only *then* writing to that memory.

If you don't want to use these functions, then one way would be to have the string already constructed i.e. use something like

```
std::string C = A; // sets up a string which is the same as A
```

Now you can safely access `C[i]` in your code because it's already of size `A.size()`. There is another way to construct a string of a certain size like

```
std::string C = std::string(count, ch)
```

where `count` is the number of characters you want initially in the string and `ch` is the character you want to be copied `count` no. of times. So something like:

```
std::string C = std::string(A.size(), '1');
```

would construct something like `"111000"` if `A` is of length 6.

Bottomline: You ***always*** need to ensure to access only allocated memory.

Comment: Apart from append , insert , push_back..is there any other way to make it work with the same code ? Like without these appending or adding to the string functions.